# Split single string into character array using ONLY bash

Tags: bash, string, split

I want to split `'hello'` into `h e l l o` in an array using only bash, I could do it in sed with `sed 's/./& /g'` but I want to know how to split a string into an array in Bash when I do not know what the delimiter would be, or the delimiter is any single character.  I don't think I can use `${i// /}` without some creativity because the delimiter is an unknown, and I don't think that expression accepts regex.  I tried using BASH_REMATCH with [[ string =~ ([a-z].).* ]] but it doesn't work as I expected.  What is the proper way to use only bash to accomplish a `string.split()` type of behavior?  The reason is that I am trying to write the rev utility in all bash:

```
  while read data; do
  word=($(echo $data|tr ' ' '_'|sed 's/./& /g'))
  new=()
  i=$((${#word[@]} - 1))
  while [[ $i -ge 0 ]]; do
    new+=(${word[$i]})
    (( i-- ))
  done
  echo ${new[@]}|tr -d ' '|tr '_' ' '
  done
```

But I used tr and sed, I want to know how to do the split properly and then I will fix it to be all bash.  Just for fun.

Comment: There must be cross-site duplicates on Stack Overflow, given the size of it. One candidate is *[Bash: Split string into character array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578930)*.

Comment: `[[ $string =~ ${string//?/(.)} ]]` will set `BASH_REMATCH[]` as required, see my answer to the question Peter Mortensen links to for an explanation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
s="hello"
declare -a a   # define array a
for ((i=0; i<${#s}; i++)); do a[$i]="${s:$i:1}"; done
declare -p a   # print array a in a reusable form
```

Output:

```
declare -a a='([0]="h" [1]="e" [2]="l" [3]="l" [4]="o")'
```

---

or (please note the comments)

```
s="hello"
while read -n 1 c; do a+=($c); done  <<< "$s"
declare -p a
```

Output:

```
declare -a a='([0]="h" [1]="e" [2]="l" [3]="l" [4]="o")'
```

Comment: The second one is nice but it only works (in this case) because you don't quote "$c", so it will drop whitespace and expand stars in $s.

Comment: The second option should be:  `while read -N 1 c; do a+=("$c"); done  <<< "$s"`. The `-N` allows to read even newlines, and the quotes `("$c")` avoid pathname expansion (and some other issues).

Comment: Of course, if the last newline must be corrected, change the line given to: `while read -N 1 c; do a+=("$c"); done <<< "$s"x` and then erase the last newline and the x added:   `unset a[${#a[@]}-1]; unset a[${#a[@]}-1]`.

Answer (score 5):

To split string into array of characters, with null delimiter, you can:

```
str='hello'
arr=()
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt "${#str}" ]; do
  arr+=("${str:$i:1}")
  i=$((i+1))
done

printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

With delimiter other than null, you can:

```
set -f
str='1,2,3,4,5'
IFS=',' arr=($str)
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: If `IFS` can be set, then you can just do: `IFS=',' arr=($str)`.

Comment: @muru: You will be stucked with glob in that case. Updated with disabling glob.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: Ah, yes, my bad, missing quote. Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun (and other shells) other variant:

```
word=hello
unset letter
while [ ${#word} -gt 0 ]
do
    rest=${word#?}
    letter[${#letter[*]}]=${word%$rest}
    word=$rest
done
```

And check

```
for l in "${!letter[@]}"
do
    echo "letter [$l] = ${letter[l]}"
done
```

will print

```
letter [0] = h
letter [1] = e
letter [2] = l
letter [3] = l
letter [4] = o
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Oneliner:

```
s="hello"
for ((i=0;i<${#s};i++)); do result[$i]="${s:i:1}"; done
echo ${result[@]}
```

Expanded code:

```
s="hello"                   # Original string.

for ((i=0;i<${#s};i++)); do # For i=0; i<(length of s); i++
    result[$i]="${s:i:1}"       # result[i] is equal to the i th character of $s
done                        # End of the loop

echo ${result[@]} # Print all elements of $result.
```

---

**Method 2:**

Oneliner:

```
s="hello"
var=($(while read -n 1; do printf "$REPLY "; done <<< "$s"))
echo "${var[@]}"
```

Expanded code:

```
s="hello" # Original string.

while read -n 1; do # Read chraracter by character the string.
    space_separated=$(printf "$space_separated $REPLY") # $space_separated is equal to it plus the current character.
done <<< "$s" # Pass the string to the loop

result=($space_separated) # Split $space_separated into an array.

echo "${result[@]}" # Print all elements of $result.
```

---

**Thanks to [@cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm) by it's suggestion.**
Effectively, you can use `$REPLY` that is the default varible where `read` reads the input.

Comment: You can use `$REPLY` instead of `char` variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34634535/2332068

```
  [[ "${text}" =~ ${text//?/(.)} ]] && array=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}")
```

I used on bash 4.3 this replacement for ${data@Q}

```
shell-escape-to() {
  local REPLY="${*:2}"
  [[ "${*:2}" =~ ${REPLY//?/(.)} ]] && printf -v "$1" "\\%c" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1}"
}
...
shell-escape-to dir_ "$dir"
sg "$GROUP" "exec mkdir -m 775 -p ${dir_}"
```

bash 4.4 and above would be:
sg "$GROUP" "exec mkdir -m 775 -p ${dir@Q}"