# Break down string into array in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am trying to convert string for example `string=11111001` to array which I will be able to access by calling respective array index like

```
arr[0]=1, arr[1]=0
```

I am new to shell scripting and from what I read, it doesn't have a separator I am stuck.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the string backwards; aren't the first two values both 1's? Your question indicates `arr[1]=0` with a string of `11....`.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/197265/117549

Comment: Since you're new to shell scripting, a piece of advice: bash is great for dealing with files and processes.  For dealing with data, strings, or algorithms, not so much.  When you start doing computationally tricky stuff, generally the best way to do it in bash is to call an external command.  Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303387/135943

Answer (score 7):

`bash` already has a form of this by way of string slicing:

```
$ word="word"
$ printf "%s\n" "${word:0:1}"
w
$ printf "%s\n" "${word:1:1}"
o
```

The syntax for this is `${variable:start:length}`, and will return the next *`length`* characters starting at the *`start`* ᵗʰ character (zero-indexed).

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${word:2:2}"
rd
```

Comment: [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) uses the term "offset" in place of "start". Nevertheless, great advice.

Comment: and `${#word}` to get the length

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, with `zsh`, to split a string into:

#### its *character* constituents:

```
chars=( ${(s[])string} )
```

(if `$string` contains bytes not  forming parts of valid characters, each of those will still be stored as separate elements)

#### its *byte* constituents

you can do the same but after having unset the *multibyte* option, for instance locally in an anonymous function:

```
(){ set -o localoptions +o multibyte
  bytes=( ${(s[])string} )
}
```

#### its *grapheme cluster* constituents.

You can use PCRE's ability to match them with `\X`:

```
zmodload zsh/pcre
(){
  graphemes=()
  local rest=$string match
  pcre_compile -s '(\X)\K.*'
  while pcre_match -v rest -- "$rest"; do
    graphemes+=($match[1])
  done
}
```

(that one assumes the input contains text properly encoded in the locale's charmap).

---

With `string=$'Ste\u0301phane'`, those give:

```
chars=( S t e ́ p h a n e )
bytes=( S t e $'\M-L' $'\M-\C-A' p h a n e )
graphemes=( S t é p h a n e )
```

As the `e` + U+0301 grapheme cluster (which display devices usually represent the same as the `é` U+00E9 precomposed equivalent) is made up of 2 characters (U+0065 and U+0301) where in locales using UTF-8 as their charmap, the first one is encoded on one byte (0x65), and the second on two bytes (0xcc 0x81, also known as Meta-L and Meta-Ctrl-A).

For strings made up only of ASCII characters like your `11111001`, all three will be equivalent.

Note that in `zsh` like in all other shells except ksh/bash, array indices start at 1, not 0.

Answer (score 4):

You could split the string on individual characters:

```
string=11111001
echo "$string" | grep -o .
```

and read them back as an array:

```
readarray -t arr <<<"$(grep -o . <<<"$string")"
```

Then, of course, each character would be at each index of the `arr` array.

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="1" [4]="1" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="1")
```

But why create a new array if bash could access each individual character  directly as this:

```
$ string=11111001
echo "${string:5:1}" "${string:7:1}"
0 1
```

Read about `${parameter:offset:length}` in `man bash`.

Answer (score 4):

A more verbose way to read a string one character at a time:

```bsh
string=11111001
arr=()

while IFS= read -r -d "" -n 1 char; do
    arr+=("$char")
done < <(printf '%s' "$string")

declare -p arr
```

outputs

```bsh
declare -a arr=([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="1" [4]="1" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="1")
```

Comment: Note that a string such as `string=$'\xf0\x80++'` in a UTF-8 locale would be split into `$'\xf0\x80+` and `+`.

Answer (score 3):

With `bash` 4.4+, as `bash` can't store NUL characters in its variables anyway, you could call a different utility to do the splitting and print the result NUL-delimited, which you can read into an array with `readarray -td ''`.

If your system comes with the GNU implementation of `grep`, you could do:

```
readarray -td '' bytes < <(printf %s "$string" | LC_ALL=C grep -zo .)
readarray -td '' chars < <(printf %s "$string" | grep -zo .)
readarray -td '' graphemes < <(printf %s "$string" | grep -zPo '\X')
```

All but the first will skip bytes that don't form part of valid characters in the locale (at least with GNU `grep` 3.4). For instance, with `string=$'Ste\u0301phane \\\xf0\x80z.'` (the trailing part not forming valid UTF-8), in a UTF-8 locale, that gives:

```
declare -a bytes=([0]="S" [1]="t" [2]="e" [3]=$'\314' [4]=$'\201' [5]="p" [6]="h" [7]="a" [8]="n" [9]="e" [10]=" " [11]="\\" [12]=$'\360' [13]=$'\200' [14]="z" [15]=".")
declare -a chars=([0]="S" [1]="t" [2]="e" [3]="́" [4]="p" [5]="h" [6]="a" [7]="n" [8]="e" [9]=" " [10]="\\" [11]="z" [12]=".")
declare -a graphemes=([0]="S" [1]="t" [2]="é" [3]="p" [4]="h" [5]="a" [6]="n" [7]="e" [8]=" " [9]="\\" [10]="z" [11]=".")
```

If not on a GNU system, and assuming `$string` contains valid UTF-8 text, you could use `perl` instead:

```
readarray -td '' bytes < <(perl -0le 'print for split "", shift' -- "$string")
readarray -td '' chars < <(perl -CSA -0le 'print for split "", shift' -- "$string")
readarray -td '' graphemes < <(perl -CSA -0le 'print for shift =~ /\X/g' -- "$string")
```

Comment: If I try your example `string=$'Ste\u0301phane \\\xf0\x80z.'` with Raku like so:  `arrayCH=($(printf %s "$string" | raku -e slurp.comb.print))` I obtain the error `Malformed UTF-8 near bytes 5c f0 80  in block <unit> at -e line 1`. (Errors with `printf` or `echo` on `$string`). However using `echo` directly on the string does not error out:  `arrayCH=($(echo 'Ste\u0301phane \\\xf0\x80z.' | raku -ne .comb.print)); echo "${arrayCH[@]}"` returns `S t e \ u 0 3 0 1 p h a n e \ \ \ x f 0 \ x 8 0 z .`

Comment: @jubilatious1, you'd need `echo -E $'...'` or `echo -e '...'` assuming an `echo` implementation that supports those options, if you want those `\u0301`, `\x...` to be expanded.

Comment: Thanks, Stéphane. It looks like my `echo` is too old.

Comment: @jubilatious1, you'd get the `echo` builtin of `bash`, but looking at your answer, that would indeed be from a 15 year old version of bash (3.2 is from 2006), so while it would support `-e` and `-E` (as long as the `xpg_echo` and `posix` options are not enabled), it likely wouldn't support `\u0301`. To output the UTF-8 encoding of the U+0301 character in there, you'd use: `printf '\314\201'`. In any case `readarray -d` needs 4.4 (from 2016) or above.

Comment: It can be done in Raku like so: `arrayCH=($(raku -e '"Ste\x[301]phane".comb.print')); echo "${arrayCH[@]}"` returns: `S t é p h a n e` . I don't think Raku supports the `\u0301` format, but maybe a regex might do, to generate the input string above.

Answer (score 2):

```
string=11111001
read -a array <<< $(echo "$string" | sed 's/./& /g')
```

`sed` to split the string by spaces separated.

Comment: That assumes `$string` doesn't contain backslashes nor newlines nor characters of `$IFS` and is not something like `-Enee` and that `$IFS` contains the space character.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6):**

```
~$ OLDIFS="$IFS"
~$ IFS=" "
~$ string=11111001
~$ read -a array <<< "$(raku -e lines.comb.print <<<"$string")"
~$ declare -p array
declare -a array='([0]="1" [1]="1" [2]="1" [3]="1" [4]="1" [5]="0" [6]="0" [7]="1")'
~$ IFS="$OLDIFS"
~$ echo -n "$IFS" | raku -e 'dd($*IN.slurp);'
" \t\n"
```

**Unicode in Raku:**
According to the docs, *"Raku applies normalization by default to all input and output except for file names, which are read and written as UTF8-C8; graphemes, which are user-visible forms of the characters, will use a normalized representation."* So the code/characters below give the following results:

```
~$ OLDIFS="$IFS"
~$ IFS=" "
~$ string1="palmarés,Würdigung,Témoignages d'honneur"
~$ read -a array1a <<< "$(raku -e lines.subst\(/"\s"/,｢_｣\).split\(｢,｣\).print <<<"$string1")"
~$ echo "${array1a[@]}"
palmarés Würdigung Témoignages_d'honneur
~$ declare -p array1a
declare -a array1a='([0]="palmarés" [1]="Würdigung" [2]="Témoignages_d'\''honneur")'

~$ read -a array1b <<< "$(raku -e lines.comb.print <<<"${array1a[2]}")"
~$ echo "${array1b[@]}"
T é m o i g n a g e s _ d ' h o n n e u r
~$ declare -p array1b
declare -a array1b='([0]="T" [1]="é" [2]="m" [3]="o" [4]="i" [5]="g" [6]="n" [7]="a" [8]="g" [9]="e" [10]="s" [11]="_" [12]="d" [13]="'\''" [14]="h" [15]="o" [16]="n" [17]="n" [18]="e" [19]="u" [20]="r")'
~$ IFS="$OLDIFS"
~$ echo -n "$IFS" | raku -e 'dd($*IN.slurp);'
" \t\n"
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode#Normalization
https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/master/docs/strings.asciidoc
[code tested on: *GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14*]

**EDIT_1:** The 'right' way to handle strings with embedded newlines appears to be slurping the string instead of reading with Raku's `ne` commandline flag, i.e. `raku -e slurp.comb.print` instead of `raku -ne .comb.print`. Then `$IFS` can be tuned to create an array using (or ignoring) newlines.

**EDIT_2:** As noted by @StephaneChazelas and @roaima, asterisks (`*`s) are problematic due to file-globbing. Here's code showing that quotation here (and above) is proper:

```
~$ string_star="*11111001"
~$ echo "$string_star"
*11111001
~$ read -a array_star <<< "$(raku -e slurp.comb.print <<<"$string_star")"
~$ echo "${array_star[@]}"
* 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Double-quoting is essential (above), however as an extra measure Raku can be used to delete all `*` by adding a call such as `.subst(...)`, (here substituting with nothing). Work-in-progress code below (consider applying same approach to delete other special characters in `bash` such as `\`, `[`, and `?`):

```
~$ read string_nostar <<< "$(raku -e slurp.subst\(｢*｣\).print <<<"$string_star")"
~$ read -a array_nostar <<< "$(raku -e slurp.comb.print <<<"$string_nostar")"
~$ echo "${array_nostar[@]}"
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: Try with `string='* *'` for instance.

Comment: I edited my post, adding code to remove `*`'s from input strings. See "EDIT_2". (Also, I tried to address embedded newlines with "EDIT_1").

Comment: `*` is not the only problem. wildcard characters, newlines and all characters in $IFS are. It also assumes `$IFS` contains the SPC character. See [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346). When using the split+glob operator like you do here by leaving that `$(...)` unquoted in list context, you need to remember to tune it (set `$IFS` to the list of separator you want and disable glob if not wanted).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas edited, generally after the reference you cited https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/227738 , but also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418930/7270649